# Design view in aspx doesnt load

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

If I click "Design" the code still shows (but is not selectable). If I minimize and maximize it shows the below instead of the designer.

I have tried repairing VS2015 and safe mode, still doesn't work. I also tried setting the default "Open With" program, but nothing changed no matter what I set.

HTML files have the same problem.
I have tried rebooting as well.
Running Windows 10

Nothing has been changed recently.

What is causing this?

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows are you running it on?

Comment: @Dai Edited. Windows 10... clean install.

Comment: This is a bug in Visual Studio. Can you file a support incident for us to take it further? (I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: @Dai Really? Link please?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: @Dai says "You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection." Why don't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94375/discussion-between-jabfreeware-and-dai).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tj8hM.png

Comment: After @Dai 's comment, I wonder if I should delete my answer since it's bringing absolutely nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody gets here via google, as I did myself when I encountered this behavior:

I was able to solve the error by installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (Version 14.0.25123.00) from the installation DVDs .iso-image.
You can check the version you're running by navigating to *HELP > About Microsoft Visual Studio*

[image: About VS 2015]

After doing so, i was able to access the designer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. So far its hit and miss. Once in a while the problem comes back and I have to do a repair a certain way.

Comment: This does not always work.  I have this issue with Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: Any update on this issue guys? I am facing this issue with v14.0.25425.01 Update 3

Comment: I'm also on Update 3 and face the same issue

Comment: I repaired my Visual Studio and now it works. It somehow corrupted my Windows User Account, though, and it had to be restored from a backup by our sysadmins. Don't know if that was related.

Comment: I'm also running 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 by now and everything is fine,  but please note that I pointed out that this issue was solved (for me) by installing Update 2 not Update 3. 

It's possible the bug has been re-introduced in Update 3. Or it hasn't been solved at all but was instead temporally fixed by the .msi-installer that I ran to upgrade to Update 2. I would suggest to do a clean re-install if the error persists - even though im aware that this isn't a very  useful advice in a productive development environment...