# VS2015 Design view unresponsive issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am able to work in the Source view with no problems.  However, as soon as I click Design the source freezes and hangs.  The same thing happens when I switch to Split as well. I cannot find much documentation/support for this issue and wondered if anyone else ran into this as well or has a potential fix?

Comment: Try cleaning solution beforehand. I believe I've read about this bug. Or clean-->restart VS--> rebuild

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately no luck.  It was worth a try though.

Comment: did you try anything from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021049/visual-studio-2015-crashes

Comment: Yep, still nothing.  I'm absolutely at a loss for what's causing this because if I create a new webform project, I have no problem getting to design.  So it must be an issue with the application configuration itself??? Either way thanks for at least pointing me in some direction.

Comment: maybe try copying designer code to new project and see there or inspect it carefully for errors.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556927/design-view-in-aspx-doesnt-load/36400792

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please make sure you have selected the project/solution you are working on ,on the left bar (esp. if working with multiple projects.)

When that is done, clean and rebuild your solution. When this is done , try again.

If all fails, restart your machine and IIS (in that order) and try again.