# Loading Design View - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I created a simple ASP web site with 'Default.aspx web form' in VS 2015.I have problem with loading 'design view'.Visual Studio doesn't display design view. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/394rC.png)

Comment: what happen after click on it?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the error by installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (Version 14.0.25123.00) from the installation DVDs .iso-image. You can check the version you're running by navigating to HELP > About Microsoft Visual Studio

You can refer to this solution [Design view in aspx doesnt load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556927/design-view-in-aspx-doesnt-load)